# Pyomo beginner : How to avoid recursion errors in pyomo when the model expressions call each other?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pyomo

I am trying to setup a model that maximizes battery profit. As part of the model, the following two quantities are defined

```latex
### Actual energy delivered during activation

The actual energy delivered $E_{del,m}$ at minute $m$ when the asset is activated during a frequency deviation differs from the expected energy $E_{\exp,m}$ because the battery can deliver energy based on the state of charge limits ($SOC_{min}$,$SOC_{max}$) and the state of charge at minute $m$, $SOC_{m}$. The actual energy delivered is then calculated as follows: 

\begin{align*} E_{del,m} = \begin{cases} {\max \left ({E_{\exp,m}, \frac {SOC_{\min } - SOC_{m} }{100} \cdot E_{rated} }\right)} &~ {P_{av,m} \ge 0} \\ {\min \left ({E_{\exp,m}, \frac {SOC_{\max } - SOC_{m} }{100} \cdot E_{rated} }\right)} &~ {P_{av,m} < 0} \end{cases}, \\\tag{9}\end{align*}

The state of charge for minute $m+1$ is calculated as follows: 

\begin{equation*} SOC_{m+1} = SOC_{m} + 100 \cdot \frac {E_{del,m} }{E_{rated} }\tag{10}\end{equation*}
```

This is how I tried to define the model :

```py
#Calculation of SOC for minute m
def calculate_SOC_m (model, m):
    if m == model.m.first():
        return SOC_init
    else:
        return model.SOC_m[m-1] + (100 * model.E_del_m[m-1]/ E_rated)
model.SOC_m = pyo.Expression (model.m, rule=calculate_SOC_m)

#Calculation of actual delivered energy in minute m based on SOC 
def calculate_E_del_m(model, m):
    if P_av_m[m]>= 0:
        return max(model.E_exp_m[m], ((SOC_min - model.SOC_m[m])/100) * E_rated)
    else:
        return min(model.E_exp_m[m], ((SOC_max - model.SOC_m[m])/100) * E_rated)
model.E_del_m = pyo.Expression (model.m, rule=calculate_E_del_m)
```

There is a Pyomo Execption error encountered because the expressions indirectly call each other. Is there a way to access the real time calculations for each variable indexed by 'm' ?

Answer (score 0):

`max()` and `min()` are non-linear functions and are NOT supported in `pyomo` framework (when operating on variables).  Its not real clear what you are trying to do with the indexed expressions, but you'll need to reformulate.

Further, it isn't clear what `P_av_m[]` is.  Conditional ("if") statements are illegal when they refer to variables as well, if that is a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Just to clarify, Pa_av_m[] is an indexed parameter whose values are fed to the model.  The others are parameters required to be calculated by the same index. 
Are there any suggestions how to work around the max() and min() problem?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do with the min/max there are generally options.  Sometimes introducing a "helper variable" that you can then constrain to be larger (or smaller) than both items will work as it will capture the min/max.  Or if you are just constraining some variable, you could constrain it to be less than or greater than both items, essentially catching the min/max.  This of course, depends on the "sense" of the optimization.